# Как получит расстояние между а пункта до б пункта КМ

Tags: php, laravel, map

Здравствуйте есть такой вопрос как получит расстояние между а пункта до б пункта через php
пример введу первий город и второй город и мне показает расстояние между ним
попробовал яндекс карту и гугл карту оба платние нужен бесплатную версию
заранее спасибо за акцент извините

Comment: Гугл платный? С каких пор... [Google Maps API: Directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions) - обычный get запрос, origin - откуда, destination - куда. На той же странице есть и [примеры](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#ExampleRequests)

Comment: Нужно получить расстояние по маршруту (по дорогам, например) или расстояние от A до Б по прямой? Координаты А и Б известны?

Comment: да гугл платний нужно расстояние  по дорогам

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно расстояние "по прямой", то можно использовать нечто такое:

```
function get_distance_between_earth_coordinates($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
    $earth_radius_km = 6371;

    $lat_rad = deg2rad($lat2-$lat1);
    $lon_rad = deg2rad($lon2-$lon1);

    $lat1 = deg2rad($lat1);
    $lat2 = deg2rad($lat2);

    $a = sin($lat_rad/2) * sin($lat_rad/2) +
          sin($lon_rad/2) * sin($lon_rad/2) * cos($lat1) * cos($lat2); 
    
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1-$a)); 
    
    return ceil($earth_radius_km * $c);
}

echo  get_distance_between_earth_coordinates(55.75399399999374, 37.62209300000001, 54.62904448341181, 39.739707746093764); //Москва - Рязань по прямой ~184 км
```

Comment: Спасибо большое